# how to do mathematical operations using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<emp>
    <emp_name>jhon</emp_name>
    <emp_sal>2000</emp_sal>
    <emp_sal1>1000</emp_sal1>
    <emp_total>10</emp_total>
</emp>
```

Based on above xml data:, i want to calculate : `emp_sal * emp_sal1 / emp_total` in XSLT.

I am trying to with `xsl:template` , as i am newbie to xslt .can anyone please help me.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 2):

It's almost that. In XPath you have to use `div` instead of `/`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="emp">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="emp_sal * emp_sal1 div emp_total"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
<result>200000</result>
```

The template maches a *node* in the source document (`<emp>`), which creates the *context* for the node names used in the XPath expression (`emp_sal`, `emp_sal1` and `emp_total`) in the `xs:value-of select`.